# why does node 14 or above does not work even when I'm running windows 8.1?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I'm learning React.Js right now, so I'm using create-react-app but when I run
`npx create-react-app my-app` i get this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ord.png)

I'm already running Windows 8.1 and have node 13.14.0, I'm trying to install the latest node version but even 14.0.0 does not work and I get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrIZp.png)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your current version of Node, and reinstall the latest (16.x.x LTS) version from the [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: I'd also recommend to install 16.x.x LTS, because it has  Long-term support. As a rule of thumb, I'd always go with even numbered major versions of Node

Comment: Yes I agree, I would do the same, I'm editing my answer

Comment: Yeah, it did not work I'm still getting error 'this application is only supported on Windows 8.1 or higher. so any other solutions

Comment: can I install an older version of create-react-app?